# I can't find file phvr7t

Tags: fonts, texlive

I installed TeXLive on Ubuntu 14.04 like this:

```
$ apt-get install -y texlive-latex-extra
```

Now I'm trying to compile my file that has this:

```
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
>> kpathsea: Running mktextfm phvr7t

>> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
>> mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input phvr7t
>> This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
>>
>> kpathsea: Running mktexmf phvr7t
>>
>> ! I can't find file `phvr7t'.
>> <*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input phvr7t
>>
>> Please type another input file name
>> ! Emergency stop.
>> <*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input phvr7t
>>
>> Transcript written on mfput.log.
>> grep: phvr7t.log: No such file or directory
>> mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input phvr7t' failed to make phvr7t.tfm.
>> kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
>> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd)
>> ! Font OT1/phv/m/n/12=phvr7t at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
>> d.
>> <to be read again
>>>  relax
>> l.68  \normalfont
>>
>> ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install more fonts. This should be possible with something like `tlmgr install psnfss` (if necessary; I doubt it) and more importantly `tlmgr install helvetic`. Sometimes figuring out font package naming can be difficult…

Comment: Can you confirm this definitely worked for you? I was just guessing :)

Comment: Worked for me. Good guess :)

Comment: slightly off-topic, but in ubuntu/debian I had to install texlive-fonts-recommended using apt-get

Comment: Can find the names of relevant packages by using the package manager. E.g. `tlmgr list phvb7t` or `tlmgr search --file phvb7t --global`.

Comment: Steffen's solution worked for me: apt install texlive-fonts-recommended

Comment: Figuring it out: `phv` = Postscript HelVetica, amd the rest are style and size. This is why TeX Gyre Heros is `qhv`, originally for Quasi-HelVetica. It all had to fit into eight characters in the days of MS-DOS, which is why old family names are like `cmr` and new ones are like `LinguisticsPro-TLF`.